Red error text below input loses contrast on input focus on Windows
I have a simple input and validation error text. These elements are placed on a dark background.
Problem is, when validation error text is visible and I click on the input field, error text loses contrast and becomes "thinner". No styles are being changes in Web Inspector.
If I have light background or put text before input (not under), this error does not appear.
This bug appears only on Windows, macOS does not have this issue. I tested it on Windows 11, Chrome 126.
To reproduce, put this code into HTML file and open it in Windows, click on the input and observe how error text changes appearance.


<div style="background: black">
  <input type="text" />
  <p style="color: red">some text</p>
</div>



Stackblitz link with Demo


Question is, how can I keep styles consistent, so that error text won't change on input focus?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Paulie_D, added code snippet.

...and the CSS and relevant JS?

I do not see it in Win 10 on Chrome 126

What resolution/Hz is the screen you're running windows OS on? iMacs/Macbooks tend to have high pixel density retina screens, so in comparison to a screen with a poorer pixel density, some CSS styling seems to look a bit different, at least from personal experience.

I can see the described issue on Win 10, Chrome 126, so it sounds like it's not related to/more specific than, OS and browser.

This is because outline is added to <input> on focus. You can change outline to something else, like box-shadow. Or, to optimize  browser work, add will-change:


input {
  will-change: opacity;
}
<div style="background: black">
  <input type="text">
  <p style="color: red;">some text</p>
</div>



